# How can I power Three Horns Valley's Happy Pig Motel?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'd like to repower the motel in "Three Horns - Valley" (particularly to use the Fast-Travel Station). All of the items in the motel are unusable (hover action says "unpowered"). When is this possible? I see a drilling rig but the switch near it does nothing when activated.

Comment: Good question !! Was thinking the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoiler below!!!

You eventually get a quest in Three Horns Valley, called "No Vacancy".  Scooter goes on to explain that the motel got wiped out by someone:

The quest states: 
        You found the abandoned Happy Pig Motel. Scooter has asked you to turn the town's power back on so you can use the motel's vending machines and bounty board.

Objective:  Turn in steam pump.

Quest spoiler:

You find out that the steam pump isn't functioning because it is broke.  Scooter then tells you to collect some parts to fix the steam pump:

Steam valve
Capacitor
Gearbox

You get this quest from an ECHO recorder pinned to the deactivated bounty board.

Comment: Sorry for poor formatting.  I an posting from my cell phone